# Apply keyboard event to input element

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, keyboard-events

I'm trying to listen to keyboard events in contenteditable and apply the same events to an input element (or applying e.keyCode to an input).  I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically).  Element.dispatchEvent will only trigger event listeners but don't seem to change the input value.

But it doesnt update the input value.  I don't want to rely on manually modifying the input.value because i need to account for things like backspace.

```
contentEditableDiv.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

Reason why i need this:
When user enters a hotkey, i show a context menu so the user can continue typing and i can filter the list, i want to throw all those events into an input so that i can use the input value to filter through my list.

Comment: What happens if you also dispatchEvent to the contentEditableDiv  ?

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
document.onkeypress = (e) => console.log(e)
```

[image]